# go back to the previous form (c#)

Tags: c#, forms, modal-dialog, back-button

I know how to go to another form in modal mode just like what I did below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 myNewForm = new Form2();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        myNewForm.ShowDialog();


    }
}
```

This is my second form, how do I go back to the previous form?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        // what should i put here to show form1 again
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `ShowDialog` on a form, it runs until the form is closed, the form's `DialogResult` property is set to something other than `None`, or a child button with a `DialogResult` property other than `None` is clicked.  So you could do something like

```
public partial class Form1
{
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        newform.ShowDialog();
        // We get here when newform's DialogResult gets set
        this.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2
{
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This hides the form, and causes ShowDialog() to return in your Form1
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Although if you're not doing anything but returning from the form when you click the button, you could just set the `DialogResult` property on Form2.button1 in the form designer, and you wouldn't need an event handler in Form2 at all.

Answer (score 1):

I use a static Form value Current in all my multiple form apps.

```
public static Form1 Current;

public Form1()
{
    Current = this;

    // ... rest of constructor
}
```

Then in Form2

```
public static Form2 Current;

public Form2()
{
    Current = this;

    // ... rest of constructor
}
```

Then you can from your button click do,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    // what should i put here to show form1 again
    Form1.Current.ShowDialog(); // <-- this
}
```