# c# navigate or skip forms

Tags: c#, forms, navigation

i learned earlier how to move between two forms back and forth. but what if there's more forms?
this is my code for form1:

```
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    private void aboutoldtrafford_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        form2.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
```

i can go to form2 and there's two button there: back and next

```
     private void backbutton_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    private void nextbutton_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            this.Hide();
            form3.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();

    }
```

back button will return to form1 and the next button will go to form3. below is my code for form3.
in form3, there are two buttons: back and finish

```
    private void back_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void finish_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        // i want to go back to form1

    }
```

back button will return to form2 and the finish button will go back to form1.
obviously, i cant do "this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;" in the finish button.
how can i go back to form1 without going to form2? please help...

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260221/go-back-to-the-previous-form-c

Comment: haha, yes but the answer i got was between two forms only..i got a problem working with so many forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option - you can use UserControls instead of Forms and just call BringToFront() on control that you want to make active.

Another option - move application state management to some object. Create states map

```
public class StateManager
{
   private Dictionary<ApplicationState, Form> _stateMap = new Dictionary<ApplicationState, Form>();
   private ApplicationState _currentState;

    public void RegisterState(ApplicationState state, Form form)
    {
        if (_stateMap.ContainsKey(state))
            // throw an exception, or rewrite mapping

       _stateMap.Add(state, form);
    }

    public ApplicationState CurrentState
    {
        get { return _currentState; }
        set
        {
            if (!_stateMap.ContainsKey(value))
                // do nothing or throw exception

            if (_currentState == value)
                return;                

            CurrentForm.Hide();                
            _currentState = value;
            CurrentForm.Show();
        }
    }

    public Form CurrentForm
    {
        get { return _stateMap[_currentState]; }
    }
}
```

I used here forms instances, but you can create instances via factory.

Next step - register states of application (of course, you should give more meaningful names for application states):

```
StateManager stateManager = StateManager.Instance;
stateManager.RegisterState(ApplicationState.Form1, new Form1());
stateManager.RegisterState(ApplicationState.Form2, new Form2());
stateManager.RegisterState(ApplicationState.Form3, new Form3());
```

Set current state and run application:

```
stateManager.CurrentState = ApplicationState.Form1;
Application.Run(stateManager.CurrentForm);
```

And last step - change applications states. You can pass stateManager instance to forms constructors, or use static Singleton:

```
private void previousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StateManager.Instance.CurrentState = ApplicationState.Form1;
}
```

Further you can create forms dynamically, use configuration file for states definition etc.

Good luck!

Comment: could you please give an example? the first code you posted, where do you put it? in the main form?

Comment: First code is separate class with own file. Registering and setting current states goes to Main() function in Program.cs file. Also for this example you'll need Singleton pattern implemented by StateManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: aw...this is too much for me, i just started learning c#...it will take a long time for me to study this..thanks for the info

Comment: Then you can create StateManager as static class (add word 'static' to class and all it's members definitions). And simply use it via static properties and methods: StateManager.CurrentState = ApplicationState.Form3. BTW ApplicationState is enum.

Comment: i know this is too much for me to ask but can you create one like. it would be very helpful if you could send me a project like this that i could study and tinker since i really dont know how to start it...

Comment: Here is static StateManager: http://www.2shared.com/file/SN9vNlI5/StaticStateManager.html Use members of StaticStateManager for steps which described above.