# How do i go back to the previous form in c#

Tags: c#

```
public ControlPanel(string userInfo)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblUserInfo.Text = userInfo;
}
```

I'm trying to go to the form above using the code below, an error message occurs:

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'user info'

```
{
    this.Hide();
    ControlPanel cp = new ControlPanel();
    cp.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Your constructor asks for an argument, you are passing none.

Comment: You should specify the `userInfo`'s value like this `new ControlPanel("")` or make it optional like this `string userInfo = ""`.

Comment: possibly duplicate of (go back to the previous form c#)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260221/go-back-to-the-previous-form-c]

Answer (score 3):

`ControlPanel` constructor requires `string userInfo` parameter.

```
this.Hide();
ControlPanel cp = new ControlPanel("SomeUserInfo");
cp.ShowDialog();
```