# How to call Form in a function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity

ı have two forms when cariGuide.cs forms cell double click function perform ı want to go Form1.cs or Form2.cs if previous form form1 or form2 ?

Here is my code block :

```
public void GoBackMain(Form frm) //
        {
            if (dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                cariModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value);
                using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
                    cariModel = db.xcaSabits.Where(x => x.Id == cariModel.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    frm.lblCariID.Text = cariModel.Id.ToString(); // cariSabitte güncelleme için id yi gönder.
                    frm.txtCariKodu.Text = cariModel.cariKodu;

                    frm.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
        }
```

My question is how to catch and understand data of previous form and send function **(Form frm)**

Comment: Please see the link below : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260221/go-back-to-the-previous-form-c?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: ı cannot convert to me because ı have 2 form to return. ı don't know how to use variables.

Comment: How about... Declare a class variable that references to the last form which you can pass it to the active form through a parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ı found it !!

First you have to declare your main form ;

```
        frmMain originalForm;
        public frmCariRehber(frmMain incomingForm)
        {
            originalForm = incomingForm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

this form is your main form which is not closing and you return the coming FORM and manage FORM with this.

After that ;

```
public void GoBackMain()
        {
            if (dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                cariModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value);
                using (fastCellDb db = new fastCellDb())
                {
                    cariModel = db.xcaSabits.Where(x => x.Id == cariModel.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    originalForm.CariID = cariModel.Id;
                    originalForm.CariKodu = cariModel.cariKodu;
                    originalForm.CariAdi = cariModel.cariIsim;
                    originalForm.CariPopulate();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my Datagridview cell click function GoBackMain().

Talk about MainForm.cs

```
public string StokKodu,CariKodu,CariAdi;
public decimal StokFiyati;
public int StokID,CariID;
```

you have to declare variables you return opening form.

and finally get the values MainForm.cs !!

```
     internal void StokPopulate()
        {
            txtStokKodu.Text = StokKodu;
            lblStokID.Text = StokID.ToString();
        }
     internal void CariPopulate()
        {
            txtCariKodu.Text = CariKodu;
            lblCariID.Text = CariID.ToString();
            lblCariGetir.Text = CariAdi;
        }
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu07ubhxyfY here is the video what ı am saying. Thanks !