# How to return back to the main form using Main function

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010

I'm coding using C# forms. I have two forms from different projects. in the form1 Main Function I want to call the form2, once form2 finishes its work it returns to form1. 
I have added form2 as a reference in form1, but when form2 finishes it doesn't return.
How can I do this return trick ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [go back to the previous form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260221/go-back-to-the-previous-form-c)

Comment: I have tried, but I cant use "this" inside Main function while it  is static

Comment: @imadsuliman Why you are using seperating projects for forms. both forms should be in single project.

Comment: Not Necessary. sometimes you will need to use a form from another projects.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution .. inside Main function of the form1:

```
 static void Main()
    {
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 form2.ShowLogin();
 Application.Run(new MainMenu());
 }
```

at the end of form2 I have added :

```
Close();
```

Inside program.cs of form2 :

```
    public static void ShowLogin()
    {
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
```